# Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-table-storage

What is exactly the azure table storage and how can i implement a good use of it, i mean what did i need to specify or the architecture to use in implementation to define a use of an Azure Table Storage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlem/archive/2008/12/20/windows-azure-storage-exploring-blobs.aspx

http://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+azure+storage

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way of learning about Table Storage is to see it in simple use:

These samples are really good for seeing each operation - http://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com/

For best practice/architecture patterns see http://azurescope.cloudapp.net/BestPractices.aspx

---

For more specific answers, you'll need to provide more specific questions - please do.